# CSP error while playing a remote audio file in Firefox WebExtension

Tags: firefox-addon, content-security-policy, firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm developing an extension that I need to play an audio from the remote server and I have another server to fetch other information.

I put the following line in `manifest.json`:

```
  "content_security_policy": "default-src 'self' https://firstserver.com https://serverwithaudio.com;"
```

I also tried

```
  "content_security_policy": "default-src 'self' https://firstserver.com; media-src  https://serverwithaudio.com;"
```

but none of them worked and I still get this error:

> Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a
>   resource at https://serverwithaudio.com/media/audio1.mp3
>   (“default-src”).

Is it possible to play a remote audio from two different sources or I missed something in my `manifest.json`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue.

First of all if you put `content_security_policy` in your `manifest.json`, you won't be able to submit it in Mozilla extension directory.

Second, I moved the audio file to the same server as I get the information. then play the audio from background script.

when I click on the button on content script I send a message to background script with the audio url:

```
 let audioUrl = "https://example.com/media/audio.mp3";
 chrome.runtime.sendMessage({audio: audioUrl});
```

And in background script:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(req, sender, sendResponse){
    if (req.audio) {
        (new Audio(req.audio)).play();
    }
    return true;
});
```

and bear in mind that you still need to mention your host in permission directive.

```
  "permissions": [
      "*://example.com/"
  ]
```

Comment: This should work for Manifest V2, but not for Manifest V3, since in Manifest V3 you can't access DOM from background scripts(service workers), which makes `Audio` undefined.